# Can anyone tell me the secret section of the manual for printf to appear

Tags: command, man, printf

I am trying to view Section 6 named  "Games and Screensavers" of the Manual. I've tried searching geeksforgeeks.org for the answer as my class suggested but I have not been able to figure it out yet.

Thank You ahead of time for any help

Comment: Why would `printf` be related to "Games and Screensavers"? Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: i think that your instructor is being funny ... probably wants to see who was listening during the lesson

Comment: What language is this for? Is it for the shell (`bash`), for `C`, or one of the many other languages that use it. Edit your question to show us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Secret section? Screensavers?  I'm curious, where did you get that from?

Answer (score 4):

The standalone `printf` utility should be documented in section 1 (*Executable programs or shell commands*). So `man 1 printf` or `man -s 1 printf` depending on the system.

However, since `printf` is also a builtin command in a multitude of different shells (with often significant differences between implementations), you will find those documented in their respective manual (still in section 1). So `man 1 dash`, `man 1 zsh`... The `zsh` manual is broken down into a few different pages. Here `man 1 zshbuiltins` (though see also `man zshall` for the huge concatenation of all those sub-pages).

In theory, you could find a `printf` man page in a `1bash` or `1zsh`, etc section, but I don't know of any system that have created dedicated man sections for the builtins of different shells.

The `fish` shell however comes with a few man pages for its builtins and concepts which it doesn't install in the standard `man` page locations, but within `fish`, replaces the `man` command with a wrapper function that tells `man` to look for man pages in there first. So within `fish`, `man printf` should describe the `fish` `printf` builtin command.

In that shell, you can also do `help printf` which should fire up a web browser to display the HTML version of the `printf` builtin manual.

If the `info` manual of `bash` or `zsh` are installed, you should be able to do `info zsh printf` or `info bash printf` to get to the section about `printf` in the info manual of those shells.

In ksh93, you can get the man page of its `printf` builtin with (within ksh93):

```
printf --man 2>&1 | less
```

Or:

```
man -l <(printf --nroff 2>&1)
```

In the `bash` shell, `help printf` will display a short help summary for the `printf` builtin.

Some systems ship with the POSIX specification of the standard `printf` utility in the `1p` or `1posix` section. That doesn't describe an actual implementation, but tells you how you should use it in a `sh` script if you expect your code to be portable.

To see the `printf` man page in every section, you can also do `man -a printf`.

To see all the section 1 `printf` man pages: `man -a 1 printf` or `man -as 1 printf`. If run within `fish` for instance, that should show the manual of the `printf` builtin, the manual of the standalone `printf` utility and (if installed) the POSIX specification of the `printf` utility, but wouldn't show the manual of the `printf()` C function or its POSIX specification (3 and 3posix sections).

On a Debian-based system, you could run `apt-file search -x '/man/man\w+/printf\.'` (after having installed `apt-file` and run `apt-file update` as `root` if not installed already), to find which package ships with what `printf` man page and in what section. Here it gives:

```
$ apt-file search -x '/man/man\w+/printf\.'
avr-libc: /usr/share/man/man3/printf.3avr.gz
coreutils: /usr/share/man/man1/printf.1.gz
fish-common: /usr/share/fish/man/man1/printf.1
freebsd-manpages: /usr/share/man/man9/printf.9freebsd.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/printf.3.gz
manpages-posix: /usr/share/man/man1/printf.1posix.gz
manpages-posix-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/printf.3posix.gz
```